# SSIS - Multiple table insert

Tags: ssis

I am copying data from MS Access to SQL Server using SSIS. Only one time I am gonna copy, it is not repeated task.

There is only one source table(Table_Source).

I want to insert data into two tables (Table1 and Table2).

Table1 contains a primary key which is a identity column.

After inserting into table1, I need to get the identity value of the row and

insert it as foreign key in table2 with some values from Table_Source.

Example:

Table_Source(EmployeeNo,LocationName)

Table1(ID,EmployeeNo)

```
                  Location(ID,LocationName) reference table
```

Table2(ID(FK to Table1),LocationID(FK to Location)

How to achieve this thro SSIS?

Thanks in advance.
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the information you need in this question: [SSIS Data Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825307/ssis-data-transformation/2827370#2827370)

Comment: Thanks Chris for the help. I will try this now.